# Can a view show all the content of groups to which a user has access?

Tags: views, 8, group

This may have been answered before, but I am not sure how to search or ask for it. My [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) knowledge is very limited, and I am not seeing a way to do this in Views at a glance.

When a user logs in to the site, and lands on the default user profile page, I want to output a view. I want to show all content *that* user has access to (from all groups they are in).

I tried adding relationships, but I can't seem to find a way to force the currently logged-in user as a relationship to what they should see.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way. Looks like you'll have to do this the good ol fashion way.

Comment: What does that mean **Groups**? Did you use module [group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)? And I think you can use the way same like  $query->addTag('node_access')

Comment: Sorry, Group.... Yes. I couldn't find the right path of Relationships in Views, either from a User -> Group -> Content attempt, or Content -> Group -> User either. The Views that ship with Group I don't really grok, the UI doesn't tell me a whole lot so I assume there must be code that goes with the View or contextual filters.

Comment: I don't even see functions like return a list of groups for a given account.

Comment: Sorry to disagree with @NoSssweat ... but when creatig such view, have you tried to start from a "group memberships" view? If you would then filter it by the current uid, you should have a list of group ids that the current user has access to (attention: "access" as defined by the Group module ...). And from there you might be able to add another relationship to all content (nodes) that belong to any of those groups.

Comment: I think I found out how... basically you have to showtheir groups first, you can’t jump directly from user to content.